# Deserializing JSON objects wrapped inside unnamed root object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have to work with an API that returns all objects wrapped in a unnamed root object. Something like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstname":"Tom",
    "lastname":"Riddle"
  }
}
```

Here, I am interested in deserializing the `user` object only. But given the nature of the response, I will have to write a class that wraps the `user` object if I want to deserialize it successfully.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
// Wrapper class
public class Info {
    private User user;
}
```

and then

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
```

All responses of the API return the response in this manner, so I am looking for a way to deserialize the response in such a way as to have one generic wrapper class that can be used to extract any type of JSON object.

I have tried this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    private T responseBody;

}
```

and then

```
ResponseWrapper<User> userInfo = objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), ResponseWrapper.class);
```

But this results in the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user" (class com.redacted.response.ResponseWrapper), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "responseBody"])
```

So, is there any way for me to deserialize this response without having to write separate wrapper classes for each API response like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(response.body().string());
String content = jsonNode.elements().next().toString();
User user = objectMapper.readValue(content, User.class);
```

Output:

```
User(firstname=Tom, lastname=Riddle)
```

Comment: Wow, this works fine. Nice and simple. I was dreading having to write a custom deserializer.